# Get a list of Names from a list of objects

Tags: c#

I have an object `Person` which contains a String field `Name`. I need to have a list of Names out of the the list of Persons in an alphabetical. Is there any smarter way of doing it without running a loop.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the select and orderby extensions, for example:

```
   var result = list.Select(i => i.Name).OrderBy(j => j);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and smart answer.

Comment: Good answer, but "i" and "j" are not very readable.  Why not use "person"?

Comment: @user1749335 I don't see any reason why an example should not be readable. Apart from this, yes, it's a good answer.